# Smooth transitions for line plots using plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

When I try this code, the lines don't transition as intended. Unwanted diagonal lines appear.  It should be that the line follows the points, which are transitioning correctly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
x=rep(seq(.1,  10, by=.1), each=10)
frame=rep(1:10, times=100)
y = floor(x)*as.numeric(x<=frame)+frame*as.numeric(x>frame)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=y, frame=frame)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(frame = frame, ids=x))+
  geom_point(aes(frame=frame, ids=x), size=.5)
ggplotly(p)
```

Here's a screen shot of what I see:

[image: Freeze frame of plotly animation showing the diagonal line]

The intended output is this, which I made with `gganimate`.  This works well, but I would like to make it using `plotly` so that it is interactive.

[image: line animation example]